# Eazy Bi - cell Formatting calculation - Average and percentage

Tags: jira, mdx, jira-plugin

Hello I am looking for an average calculation in the table.
I created an eazyBi report, so far so good it is extracting me which deliveries are on time or not.
Now I want to calculate from the calculated measures absolute Average and percentage values .
I added a picture which shows my intention. The Yellow values I photoshopped.
So is it possible to calculate the absolute values from my already calculated values in a table.
I tried several ways, maybe it is possible over the Cell Formation way.
Or someone has a better idea.
I would really appreciate some help, I have already been trying for some days.
Thanks!

[Calculated table with photoshopped absolute values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl3Vr.png)

Answer (score 0):

I reckon "On Time deliveries" is a calculated measure comparing "Issue due date" and "Actual Delivery Time". So in the "Issue" level, you can leave it at that.

In the "Project" and "All Issues" levels, I recommend a bit more complex calculation. First, create a calculated measure that will determine the number of issues on time and then divide by all issues with the delivery date:

```
CoalesceEmpty(
  Sum(
    Filter(
      Descendants([Issue].CurrentMember,[Issue].[Issue]),
      DateCompare(
        [Measures].[Issue due date],
        [Measures].[Actual Delivery Time]
      ) >=0
    ),[Measures].[Issues with due date]
  ), 0)
/
[Measures].[Issues with Actual Delivery Time]
```

Let's call it "On time issue %". Use the "decimal percentage" formatting for it. Then update the "On time deliveries" with a formula similar to the one below:

```
CASE WHEN [Issue].CurrentHierarchyMember.Level.Name = 'Issue'
THEN
  IIf(
    DateCompare(
      [Measures].[Issue due date],
      [Measures].[Actual Delivery Time]
    ) >= 0,
    "On Time",
    "Delayed"
  )
ELSE
Format([Measures].[On time issue %], "0.00%")
END
```

That should do the trick with the text formatting.

For the average, I recommend the approach below:

```
Avg(
  Filter(
    Descendants([Issue].CurrentMember,[Issue].[Issue]),
      DateCompare(
        [Measures].[Issue due date],
        [Measures].[Actual Delivery Time]
      )<0
      AND
      [Measures].[Issues with due date] > 0
  ),
  DateDiffDays(
    [Measures].[Issue due date],
    [Measures].[Actual Delivery Time]
  )
)
```

The eazyBI documentation page has details and examples for the used functions - https://docs.eazybi.com/eazybijira/analyze-and-visualize/calculated-measures-and-members/mdx-function-reference.